# Windows 10 auto hibernates randomly once for each time and for no reason?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hibernate

Since the time I used a computer running Windows (about 15 years ago), this is the first time I've encountered such a strange issue.

Every time I turn on my laptop (currently running Windows 10), randomly somehow it auto hibernates (or sleeps, I'm not so sure) even though I'm still trying to type something. Firstly I can see that the screen goes off and the indicators (for HDD, CPU, Disk …) are on for a while before going off as well (it looks much like hibernating than sleeping because it takes about several (up to 10) seconds (for a SSD system drive?). Right after that I push the power button and it comes back with all windows opened before (so actually it's not shutdown, it's hibernated or slept, not so sure). Also when re-powering it on, I can see the Windows logo appear (so again it's a sign of coming back from hibernation rather than sleep?)

It does not happen right after my laptop turns on, sometimes after about 2 minutes, sometimes after about 5 minutes or even longer.

As I said this happens randomly (but fairly frequently). I mean for each time (after turning on such as after getting back from work), it seems to happen at most one time. And sporadically it does not happen.

The only sign I can luckily detect before it goes to hibernate/sleep that way is the ***Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry*** somehow consumes up to nearly 100% CPU usage.

Do you have any suggestion to help fix this? Or at least help understand about any possible cause?

Comment: you can use Event Viewer to check about hibernation and sleep issue but from your description it looks like it Hibernates. Now it could be a hardware issue(eg. battery) or software issue. Try using the laptop without the battery for some days and check if you still face the issue. If it still hibernates then battery is not the issue. You could then use the windows 10  disk to repair your PC or perform a clean install of windows 10

Comment: maybe event viewer will show the reason for hibernation as well I am not sure about that but do check.

Comment: @Elmo thank you for your feedback, I've checked out the Event Viewer and looks like there is not anything strange there (even when applied a filter for Warning and Error events only). My laptop's battery has been completely worn out (but still installed in the tray), now it always requires a live power supply (plugged-in). Does that matter anything? I've used my laptop since that situation for about 2 years (I could not find any new genuine battery for replacement - because the ASUS Corp actually does not produce that model any more).

Comment: Remove the battery (if it is a removable battery) and then connect the power cable and power on the laptop, if it works there is no problem in using the laptop like that but just make sure that you don't disconnect the power cable while using it and don't put it on sleep.  AND if it does not start without that battery then I guess your laptop does not support the laptop without the battery..just give it a try

Comment: Check your power settings as well and restore everything to default.